# How to migrate plone 4.2 from debian squeez to wheezy

Tags: plone

I have a plone 4.2 instance in debian squeeze. Now I am trying to migrate it to a new server running wheezy: copy the plone directory from squeeze to wheezy--> run 'plonectl start'. It fails and error is shown : can not find 'plone' user.

What should I do to migrate it? Just to add user and group 'plone'? Will this affect plone_buildout and plone_group in plone 4.3?

Comment: Did you install it from the debian package or manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nearly never move a large software package from one machine to another by simply copying the files. In this case, for example, the Plone installation is set up to run as a particular system user, "plone", and you don't have that user ID on the new machine.

Instead, do a fresh install of Plone on the new machine, then copy over the data and customizations. The order should probably be:

1) Do a fresh install on the new machine, modeled as closely as possible on the old; test it;

2) Copy the instance .cfg files and anything in ./src; test it;

3) Note the ownership and permissions of your sources; tar it; unpack on the destination machine; check ownership and permissions; test it.

**If you are migrating from one Plone version to another,** you should not simply copy the .cfg files. Instead, transfer customizations from your eggs= and develop= lists. Test to see if any customizations break the new Plone. Consult the [upgrade guide](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/version/upgrading-plone-4.2-to-4.3) for details on package migration. When transferring your data, match the ownership and permissions from the target, not the source. Run the Plone migration process for each Plone instance in your install. 4.2 -> 4.3 is a largely painless upgrade.