# How to import an existing Plone-based site to a new Ubuntu server

Tags: plone

I am new to Plone framework. All I need to do might seem quite simple but I need some guidance.

I obtained files of an existing Plone-based site and want to integrate into a new Ubuntu computer. Here are the file list.

- buildout-cache
- Plone-docs
- Python-2.6
- zinstance

And in Zinstance directory I have

- adminPassword.txt
- buildout.cfg
- PloneController.app
- var
- base.cfg
- develop.cfg
- products
- versions.cfg
- bin
- develop-eggs
- README.html
- zope_versions.cg
- bootstrap.py
- parts
- src

I ran

> ./bin/plonectl start

under this site path, but I got improtError for module _md5

> ImportError: No module named _md5

I have installed openssl according to a quick internet search but I don't know if that's the problem or not.

What is the correct way to import and publish this Plone site? Thanks~

Comment: See @SteveM's answer to a very similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16590316

Answer (score 1):

This issue is more about "how to enable the md5 module in Python". After installing the required OS libs you should re-compile your python. Normally using system's python it just works because the packages management system takes care of everything but in your case, your Plone installation is using that local installation of the Python intepreter that you see in the root directory tree (Python-2.6). The shortest way to proceed for you is to [download Python](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.5/Python-2.6.5.tgz) and compile it again. After this, you should use your new Python interpreter to run this:

```
$ /<whatever>/python -c "import md5"
```

if it returns nothing then you are ready to go with this:

```
$ cd zinstance
$ /<whatever>/python bootstrap.py -v 1.7.5
$ bin/buildout -Nv
```

**Edit**:
BTW, before recompiling the Python intepreter you should take the chance to install many other system dependencies that you may need:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libglib2.0-dev libssl-dev \
libxslt-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev zlib1g-dev libjpeg62-dev \
libxml2-dev python-ldap python-dev python-tk python-lxml \
python-libxml2  wv poppler-utils xpdf libncurses5-dev libbz2-dev \
git liblcms1-dev libreadline-dev gettext
```

Comment: Thanks. What I tried later is just to copy Data.fg and other critical files like products to new system. It seems working but some links are broken. My guesses are incomplete file migration. But still I appreciate your answer!